# urlopen() and read() [urllib2]

Tags: python, exception, urllib2, urllib

I am testing for some exception handling and would want to know, which network related errors could occur in the following code:

```
candidate =  urllib2.urlopen() #1
candidate.read() #2
```

I know that `#1` causes `URLError`. Are there any other errors that could be raised? In particular does `#2` require network connection?

Answer (score 3):

Reading requires that the socket is still open; although some response data will be buffered generally you pull data down by reading. The `candidate.read()` call will block until the whole response has been read.

As such [`socket.error`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.error) (a subclass of `IOError`) can be raised even during the `candidate.read()` call.

Apart from the `urllib2.URLError` exception (plus subclass), `urllib2.urlopen()` can also raise [`httplib.HTTPException` with various subclasses](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPException), `socket.error`, or when fed invalid data (illegal URL string, etc.), `ValueError`. Once you have a response object, `response.read()` can also raise `socket.error` and `httplib.HTTPException`.

`httplib.HTTPException` is a straight `Exception` subclass. `socket.error` and `urllib2.URLError` are `IOError` subclasses.

Comment: IIRC, at least with the CPython 2.7 implementation of `urllib2` on POSIX systems with the default handlers installed, it actually buffers up the entire thing in `urlopen`, because that's what the `HTTPHandler` at the end of the chain does, so the `read` doesn't actually do anything. But yeah, going by the documentation, you definitely should assume that either of these functions could end up calling `recv` on the socket.

Comment: @abarnert: there is a buffer, but it doesn't read the whole response, no. Try `urllib2.urlopen('http://httpbin.org/drip?numbytes=10000&duration=100&delay=5&code=200')` and time how long that takes to respond, then call `r.read()` on it. It'll take longer than 5 seconds (the initial delay), but not 105 seconds either (the total time for the server to complete returning 10000 asterisks).

Comment: When I try that, the initial `urlopen` takes 6 seconds, a subsequent `read` takes another 5-6 seconds and then raises `IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(2460 bytes read)` rather than taking ~100 seconds and succeeding… But that's enough to prove your point.

Comment: @abarnert: Yes, which is why I sjust added `httplib.HTTPException` to the list.